# Request Parameters map getting empty in Mozilla

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

Our web application is using Java spring mvc framework and apache tomcat 6.0.32 and there is a POST request for which request parameter map is getting empty in Mozilla Firefox 23.0.1 while everything working fine in Chrome 28.0. Following is the screenshot attached. Any help would be highly helpful.
1st screen shot is of Chrome.
2nd screen shot is of Mozilla
3rd screen shot is of Mozilla Post.

[image: Chrome Request Header][image: Mozilla Post Data][image: Mozilla Request Header]

Comment: They look exactly the same to me `feedback=`, ie. (empty) and `rinList=45994`.

Comment: yes they are actually same, but at server side request.getParametersMap() returning an empty map.

Comment: Please show how you are using it.